# Android app getting closed every time I am running this "if else" conditional statement in an Onclick listener for a button

Tags: java, android, if-statement, android-spinner

I am a beginner in android, and currently I am working on an app which requires usage of a else if statement. Below is the code snippet of the same:

```
submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {


    if ((CCValue.equals("3") && MVValue.equals("3.5")) || (CCValue.equals("3") && MVValue.equals("4")) || (CCValue.equals("3") && MVValue.equals("5")) ||
      (CCValue.equals("4") && MVValue.equals("4.5")) || (CCValue.equals("4") && MVValue.equals("5")) || (CCValue.equals("5") && MVValue.equals("5"))) {

      thresholdValue = 1;

    } else {
      thresholdValue = 0;
    }

    threshold.setText(thresholdValue);

  }
});
```

Submit is the name of the button on which the user will click, and the compiler will go in the "if" statement. CCValue and MVValue are string variables, which I am saving from two spinners selected by the user. "thresholdValue" is an integer variable which will get value according to the if statement. Finally "threshold" is an EditText component.

Now I am trying to compare the values stored withing the string variables through the "if" condition. But every time whenever I am clicking on the submit button the app is getting crashed. What changes should I make to make this code run successfully?

Below is the logcat for the same:

```
09-03 05:59:34.209 9772-9772/? I/zygote: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
09-03 05:59:34.261 9772-9772/? W/zygote: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
09-03 05:59:34.413 9772-9779/? E/zygote: Failed writing handshake bytes (-1 of 14): Broken pipe
09-03 05:59:34.413 9772-9779/? I/zygote: Debugger is no longer active
09-03 05:59:34.617 9772-9772/? I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
09-03 05:59:35.038 9772-9783/? I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 8279(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 54% free, 1304KB/2MB, paused 5.265ms total 87.569ms
09-03 05:59:35.234 9772-9795/? D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
09-03 05:59:35.259 9772-9777/? I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=8KB, data=29KB
09-03 05:59:35.262 9772-9777/? I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=8KB, data=29KB
    Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
09-03 05:59:35.458 9772-9795/saferatestarter.dasnr.okstate.edu.glanceandgo I/zygote: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
09-03 05:59:35.458 9772-9795/saferatestarter.dasnr.okstate.edu.glanceandgo I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
09-03 05:59:35.458 9772-9795/saferatestarter.dasnr.okstate.edu.glanceandgo D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
09-03 05:59:35.459 9772-9795/saferatestarter.dasnr.okstate.edu.glanceandgo W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
09-03 05:59:35.459 9772-9795/saferatestarter.dasnr.okstate.edu.glanceandgo D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
09-03 05:59:36.249 9772-9795/saferatestarter.dasnr.okstate.edu.glanceandgo D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xed50e7c0: maj 3 min 1 rcv 4
09-03 05:59:36.418 9772-9795/saferatestarter.dasnr.okstate.edu.glanceandgo D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xed50e7c0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xed51b510)
09-03 05:59:36.420 9772-9795/saferatestarter.dasnr.okstate.edu.glanceandgo E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
    glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
09-03 05:59:36.579 9772-9772/saferatestarter.dasnr.okstate.edu.glanceandgo I/Choreographer: Skipped 77 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-03 05:59:36.600 9772-9795/saferatestarter.dasnr.okstate.edu.glanceandgo D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xed50e7c0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xed51b510)
09-03 05:59:36.854 9772-9772/saferatestarter.dasnr.okstate.edu.glanceandgo D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


    --------- beginning of crash
09-03 05:59:36.856 9772-9772/saferatestarter.dasnr.okstate.edu.glanceandgo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: saferatestarter.dasnr.okstate.edu.glanceandgo, PID: 9772
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Select"
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
        at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:539)
        at saferatestarter.dasnr.okstate.edu.glanceandgo.MainActivity$1.onItemSelected(MainActivity.java:52)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:944)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.dispatchOnItemSelected(AdapterView.java:933)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:898)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: Are you sure both CCValue and MVValue are never null? also posting the error log of the crash will make the problem clearer.

Comment: Please post logcat. most probably either CCValue or MVValue is null.

Comment: Application closes only if an activity is finished but in your case it looks like your app is crashing. Please check `adb logs` of your app for more information. Looks `NullPointerException`

Comment: we need to see the logs before we can even help you diagnose the error

Comment: try to check !ccvalue.isEmpty and !mvvalue.isEmpty()

Comment: @A.R.H thanks a lot for the quick reply sir!  I am sure that CCValue and MVValue are never null as the values are selected through spinners in which I have added the values.

Comment: @AbhishekSingh thank you for the quick response! I am updating my post with the logcat.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT:

Solution bellow would solve another crash. According to logcat, you trying to parse double out of `spinner` selected item, which can have value "Select" if nothing is chosen, so it crash at `NumberFormatException`.

ORIG:

It is caused by `threshold.setText(thresholdValue);` line. When you put int to `setText` fuction, android will look for string resource with id corresponding to int value provided. Use this instead:

```
threshold.setText(String.valueOf(thresholdValue));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I guess i figured out where the error was, I have used value xml to create list for the spinners. Below is the code which I used for the list:                                 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="MarketValueArray">
       <item> Select </item>
        <item>2</item>
        <item>2.5</item>
        <item>3</item>
        <item>3.5</item>
        <item>4</item>
        <item>4.5</item>
        <item>5</item>
        </string-array>

</resources>  I just removed "Select"

Comment: That should do the trick, as you will not try to parse it anymore :) Anyway, change the variable in `setText`, or it will crash there too.

Answer (score 0):

update the " threshold.setText(thresholdValue);" to " threshold.setText(""+thresholdValue);"

Answer (score 0):

You are converting string "select" to double value.
To convert String into double you must have string with digits.

Here i have a check for you which will check that the string only contains digits.

```
if (text.matches("[0-9]+") && text.length() > 2) {
```

}